# Automatic version management using agvtool

Tags: xcode, xcode11, agvtool

Xcode 11 has changed the way that versions are handled.

So far I had two targets, Dev & Prod, each with a separate versions. Prod version would be entirely manual, Dev would be automated:

- During a build, a script would run, which then would fetch git tags. One tag would contain information about the latest Dev version. If it's newer, it would update version inside Info.plist just for the Dev target
- When Dev would be deployed using a script (create an ipa, resign for in-house distribution, upload), the build version would then be increased. Remote tag containing version information would then be updated

In this way everyone's dev version would get automatically synchronized and managing multiple dev builds would be be easy. Prod would be updated relatively infrequently so it can be managed manually.

However, in Xcode 11 whenver version (or build) is updated inside the General tab, entries in `Info.plist` are replaced with `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)` and `$(MARKETING_VERSION)` and `Current Project Version` and `Marketing Version` inside the build settings tab is used instead.

So far I would use `PlistBuddy` in order to read and update versions inside `Info.plist`, but from what understand now I'd have to use `agvtool`. However, there are two issues with it:

- If it's ran as a Run Script phase, it causes the build process to cancel
- It is unable to handle separate versions for two targets (so I cannot just automatically manage Dev, while leaving Prod alone)

I know that theoretically I can still use `Info.plist` for versioning, but the moment someone changes version manually in the General tab, the whole thing will get messed up (from experience I know that this will happen).

I have two questions:

- Is my understanding of the process correct?
- Can still have a version management system using `agvtool` similar to what I had before?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any answers?
I did notice that you can automate with agvtool if it is the last phase of the build, which of course means your version number only gets bumped up *after* you've built, which is also less than ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I spent some more time on it, but I finally gave up and just left it as manual version management.